# Exponential time hypothesis for random algorithms

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, randomized-algorithms

The exponential time hypothesis asserts that an algorithm for SAT must take time $2^{\Omega(n)}$. If I am reading this right, this refers only to deterministic algorithms.

Is it possible that ETH holds, yet their is a random algorithm in time $2^{o(n)}$? If so, is there any name for the hypothesis that any randomized (say BPP-type) algorithm takes time $2^{\Omega(n)}$ as well?

Comment: You might want to check out http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1775v1.pdf
It introduces a number of related conjectures to the ETH, including a randomized version.

Comment: Calabro, Impagliazzo, and Paturi define the SETH explicitly with respect to randomised algorithms.  Your statement for the ETH is also incompletely specified and misleading.